# Blob corrupt when saving converted Canvas DataURL bytes to database

Tags: java, canvas, inputstream, java-2d, bytearrayinputstream

I have a canvas element in my xhtml.  I convert this to a base-64 encoded `String` called dataUrl with a `toDataUrl()` call.  This produces the following output, truncated for clarity:

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAzQAAAImCAYAAACFG89TAAAgAElEQVR4Xu29C7x/5Zj3 [lots of characters...]"
```

I want to send this image to my MySQL database.  I have a Blob (@Lob) field in my entity, and in order to convert this string to an array of bytes, use `dataUrl.getData()` and update my entity with this byte array.

In my MySQL database, the BLOB is successfully created.  However, when I right-click on it and click Open File in Editor, I see the bytes tab fine but receive a generic error when I click on the image tab, suggesting the bytes are corrupted somehow.

This means that when I want to read this file, using `BufferedImage imag = ImageIO.read(is);` where `is` is a `ByteArrayInputStream` with the bytes array as an argument, `imag` returns null, more specifically the `read` method within the `BufferedImage` class.

Edit: see screenshots, the first is the `dataUrl.getBytes()` call, the second is the MySQL output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well what values do you see in the bytes tab? What bytes did you get from `dataUrl.getData()`? Please edit your question with (say) the first 16 bytes in each case.

Comment: Updated my question with this info.

Comment: The first screenshot doesn't actually show any data, does it? Please expand the first row.

Comment: Both expanding the rows, and clicking [...] show blank output.

Comment: That would be very odd, given that you clearly are managing to store data. See my answer for what it looks like you're storing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `String.getBytes()`, I used:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] b = decoder.decodeBuffer(dataURL.split("^data:image/(png|jpg);base64,")[1]);
```

And it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it sounds like `dataUrl.getData()` isn't working for you. The bytes you're storing are basically the ASCII of "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg..." rather than the *binary* data stored within the base64 part itself.

It's possible that you're double-encoding this somewhere - it's hard to tell without seeing your code - but that's what we can see so far.

I would suggest that you look at the byte array *before* you store it in the database. The first few bytes should be 0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a. Once you've got *that* part working, if it still doesn't work you can move forward.

Basically, check the data at *every* stage of the process, so you can detect the failed-decoding/double-encoding/whatever it is.